# Confluent local start gives config.json: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

When I start confluent local start I get /users/myusername/.confluent/config.json: No such file or directory.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create the .confluent directory

Comment: Brilliant that worked I thought it's something related to java_home however java_home was already set. This creation of folder actually worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)Install the Confluent CLI, confluent, using the following script. The  parameter must be in your PATH (e.g. /usr/local/bin).

On Microsoft Windows, an appropriate Linux environment may need to be installed in order to have the curl and sh commands available, such as the Windows Subsystem for Linux https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about.

curl -L --http1.1 https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- -b /**path-to-cli**

and then go to the **path-to-cli** folder and run below command
`./confluent local start`